# Stack's 50+ credential rule is preventing open communication and turning away good answers. Why?

Tags: discussion, comments, user-accounts

This is an all too common problem. I spent `~1hr` debugging an answer an some SE site. Until I realized it was a simple typo. I had yet to make an account (usually just mooching off of other's answers as so many do), but I decided to help out the community by commenting on the answer and showing the typo. After going through the process of making an account - I realized I can't even comment yet!

I'm wondering how many typos are still out there on that SE site, because of these limits! What gives?

Comment: The min of 50rep to comment prevent a *lot* of spam or bad comments.

Comment: You might try to make an appropriate edit to point the typo out, or just fix it.

Comment: The *open communication* would be probably used as well for chit-chat which was and is exactly what we want to prevent.

Comment: You can suggest an edit. If you get an error saying that your edit is less than 6 characters and you can't find anything else to improve, you can add a `<!---->` somewhere in the post (that's an HTML comment, so it won't be visible in the post).

Comment: Comments shouldn’t be used to answer a question.  If we are turning away answers submitted as answers then that’s a very good thing.

Comment: "*I decided to help out the community by commenting on the answer and showing the typo*" Then how did we prevent a "good answer"? You weren't trying to post an answer, so we didn't lose anything in that case.

Answer (score 4):

You can always improve existing posts by editing. Especially if you detect typos it will be appreciated that you did efforts to fix these, and want to share your knowledge.

If you're restricted regarding to fix less than 6 characters, you might find something else to improve in that post most probably, or at least leave a note there, that you fixed it from an earlier version.

---

Another option is to post another answer (if there was a typo in the answer), refer to that original one and point out for the typo, and why it was that hard to debug it.

Answer (score 2):

Please review what explain within the help pages about ***editing***, especially "[Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/editing)", which includes:

> Any user can propose edits, but not all edits are publicly visible immediately. If a user has less than 2,000 reputation, the suggested edit is placed in a review queue. Two accept or reject votes are required to remove the suggested edit from the queue and either apply the edit to the post or discard it. Users with more than 2,000 reputation are considered trusted community members and can edit posts without going through the review process.

And for more details about the last phrase in the above quote, refer to the *privilege* "[edit questions and answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit)", accidentally the most recent privilege I recently earned (and which I'll use to slightly edit your question also).

Also, it takes "a little rep" to be allowed to post comments. One of the main reasons for that is that without such minimal rep requirement, it would be too easy for spam users (typically with rep = `+1`) to post all sorts of spam comments.

Bottomline: use "edit sugggestions" to start, try to gain sufficient  reputation points to gain the edit-privilege and you can contribute as much edits as you want ...